# Create named tuple from subset of dict keys

Tags: python, namedtuple

What is the most pythonic way to make the following test pass:

```
def test_named_tuple_from_map():
    from collections import namedtuple
    NT = namedtuple('nt', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    source = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 3}
    new = NT(**source)
    assert new == NT(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

The reason I want this is so that I can pick out subsets of dict data and pass on as immutable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the attribute `_fields` of the `namedtuple` and filter the dictionary accordingly:

```
def test_named_tuple_from_map():
    from collections import namedtuple
    NT = namedtuple('nt', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    source = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 4, 'c': 3}

    new = NT(**{k: v for k, v in source.items() if k in NT._fields})

    assert new == NT(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```